# Terraform to create azure subnet delegation for selected subnets using for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I want some help on creating delegation on selected azure subnets. My code is as per below details.

**Variables defined in my variable file**

```
variable “subnets” {
type = map(any)
}
```

**My tfvar file contains below values**

```
subnets = {
mlops-aue-snt-aks = [“10.255.232.0/24”]
mlops-aue-snt-stg = [“10.255.233.0/26”]
mlops-aue-snt-kv = [“10.255.233.128/27”]
AzureBastionSubnet = [“10.255.233.160/27”]
mlops-aue-snt-shd = [“10.255.234.0/25”]
mlops-aue-snt-db1 = [“10.255.235.0/26”]
mlops-aue-snt-db2 = [“10.255.235.64/26”]
mlops-aue-snt-aci = [“10.255.235.128/26”]
}
```

**This is my code for subnet**

```
resource “azurerm_subnet” “azr_subnet” {
for_each = var.subnets

name = each.key
resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
address_prefixes = each.value
enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
}
```

All subnets are created with this and it is all fine but now I have a requirement to add service_delegation for mlops-aue-snt-db1 and mlops-aue-snt-db2 and different for other subnets. I am not sure how to achieve this with my existing code. I can’t separate out subnets from the code as it will force to delete existing ones and create new which is not recommended. I did read some posts about using dynamic block to make changes but not sure how to implement it for selective subnets as per my requirement.

Can anyone please suggest how to achieve this in terraform?

Answer (score 5):

You can do this with `dynamic blocks` and by changing your `subnets` a bit.

```
subnets = {
    mlops-aue-snt-aks = {
            cidr = [“10.255.232.0/24”]
            service_delegation = false
    }    
    # the rest in same format
    mlops-aue-snt-db1 = {
            cidr = [“10.255.235.0/26”]
            service_delegation = true
    }    
    mlops-aue-snt-db2 = {
            cidr = [“10.255.235.64/26”]
            service_delegation = true
    }
    # ...
}
```

then

```
resource "azurerm_subnet" "azr_subnet" {
    for_each = var.subnets

    name = each.key
    resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.rg.name
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.vnet.name
    address_prefixes = each.value.cidr
    enforce_private_link_endpoint_network_policies = true
    
    dynamic "delegation" {
        for_each = each.value.service_delegation == "true" ? [1] : []
        
        content {
            name = "delegation"

            service_delegation {
            name    = "Microsoft.ContainerInstance/containerGroups"
            actions = ["Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/join/action", "Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/subnets/prepareNetworkPolicies/action"]
            }        
        }
    
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for your quick reply. I tried out this solution but terraform is not detecting any change to my existing infra on subnets. I am getting this message after terraform plan "No changes. Your infrastructure matches the configuration."

Comment: yes, your answer was really helpful but ideally terraform should mark it is as change which it would do in normal situation if I am creating subnet using azurerm_subnet where it will detect the change and show me the update after plan. But in this case it is not showing me any update so I doubt it will really make any change to the subnets after apply.

Comment: @Prem Thanks for letting me know. You can make new question for that providing the new, modified code that you have. It will be easier to help this way.

Comment: wanted to update you that your answer was spot on and it worked. Earlier I made some mistake so terraform was not detecting any change but then it worked perfectly fine for me. I could see the change made in subnets delegation as well. I just have 2 more points to understand. One is what is the functioning of using `[1] and []` inside `each.value.service_delegation == "true" ? [1] : []`. If you can explain that and other is how is there a way to assign different delegations to remaining subnets in this code and how? Thanks a ton once again for your help.

Comment: thanks, I have selected your reply as working solution. It would be great if you can explain the 2 queries I have asked in my previous comments.

Comment: @Prem No problem. `each.value.service_delegation == "true" ? [1] : []` the condition ensures that the dynamic block will execute only once `[1]` (what's inside the list does not matter, only that there is one element), or not `[]` (empty list, so there is nothing to iterate over).

Comment: `for_each = each.value.service_delegation == "true" ? [1] : []` doesn't work. It should be `for_each = each.value.service_delegation == true ? [1] : []`

Comment: So am i correct in assuming this for loop is effectively an if/then condition basically? if TRUE add a service delegation, otherwise skip?

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [repo](https://github.com/JamesDLD/terraform-azurerm-Az-VirtualNetwork/blob/master/main.tf). This is not my work and I am not taking credit for it. I have just decided to share it so that it can be useful for devs looking for a solution for this common problem.